# formula unique character from first char in cell text

Tags: excel

have any idea for create unique character from cell in excel?

example : 
i have string in cell 
A1 = "lorem lipsum bla bla"

and A2 with formula generate char from A1 like "LLBB"; just get first char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this small User Defined Function:

```
Public Function fLetter(rng As Range) As String
    Dim a
    For Each a In Split(rng.Value, " ")
        fLetter = fLetter & UCase(Left(a, 1))
    Next a
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

with Office 365 Excel you can use CONCAT() in an array formula:

```
=UPPER(CONCAT(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(1:20)-1)*99+1,99)))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> when exiting edit mode. If done correctly Excel will put {} around the formula.

Replace the `20` with the max number of words it can be.

[image]

Comment: not work for me `=UPPER(CONCAT(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(1:20)-1)*99+1,99)))))`

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL3Ez.png

Comment: @MarshallTelaumbanua Do you have Office 365?

Comment: @MarshallTelaumbanua Well, Scott mentioned in his response that his solution **required** Office 365 which has the `CONCAT` function.  You will need either helper columns or a VBA solution to solve this if you do not.